# Sub tags for TikZ/PGF

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are 1670 questions in the [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) tag at time of writing.  There was a [suggestion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3869668#3869668) (and thereabouts) to have some subtags.  This "question" is to gather together some ideas.

Two major threads suggest themselves to me:

#### TikZ/PGF derived packages

There are several packages (or collections of packages) that have been built on top of TikZ/PGF.  I don't know them all.

- PGFPlots (the tag [pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots) already exists)
- TKZ suite ([tkz-collection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tkz-collection), [tkz-fct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tkz-fct) and [tkz-graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tkz-graph) already exists)

#### TikZ/PGF common tasks

There are some tasks that crop up quite often.

- Decorating a path
- Manipulating a path (more low-level than decorations)
- Nodes and shapes
- Transformations

Again, I've certainly missed some.

---

As usual, tags should add information to the question and not simply add a "buzz-word".  While it may not be the case that a questioner knows what tags to add, it should be that when the tag is added, the questioner goes "Oh, of course.  If I'd known that tag existed I'd've added it."

Please add more suggestions, and comment whether or not you think this is a good idea.

Comment: There are some `tkz` related tags already, I took the liberty of editing your post to mention them.

Answer (score 4):

I think is a great idea and one could also tap ideas from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/#tags as suggested by Stefan Kottwitz. Some tags which I would like to see is `pgfkeys`,  `pgfmaths`, `foreach` etc., and your list can be a good starting point.

Comment: [tag:pgfkeys] and [tag:foreach] already exist, but maybe need to be applied more broadly.